# PSQLException error at or near "(" position 149

Tags: postgresql

Hello i am trying to upload file in postgresql database but i am getting an error:  Here is the stacktrace of code..Can anyone give me idea where things are going wrong?? My query is-

```
String sql = "insert into project_details (document_type,file_type,file_upload,status,gid,userid,s_comment,s_date,s_time) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,current_date(),current_time());";
```

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "("
  Position: 149
```

Comment: Share query you try to run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`current_date/current_time`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) instead of `current_date()/current_time()`:

```
String sql = "insert into project_details (document_type,file_type,file_upload,status,gid,userid,s_comment,s_date,s_time) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,current_date,current_time);";
```

Comment: i didn't get what you trying to convey??

Comment: @Roopam **`current_date` != `current_date()`** I hope this is clear :)

Answer (score 3):

current_date and current_time [don't have parentheses](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT):

```
insert into project_details 
   (document_type,file_type,file_upload,status,gid,userid,s_comment,s_date,s_time)
values 
   (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,current_date,current_time);
```